# Why do javascript methods have a faster runtime than writing out something similar

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, time-complexity

So I was doing some leetcode, and I wrote out a solution that was O(n). This solution was not bad but it looking at how it compared to other solutions I knew there was a faster way. I eventually found the solution, and I ended up using the method String.includes(substring). Personally I cannot think of a way that this method underneath the hood does not also take O(n), so I was wondering why using methods is faster than writing code with the same complexity. If String.includes(substring) actually is faster that O(n) underneath the hood, then that explains it, but I am still curious.

The problem was to check if the rotated string is possible:

"We are given two strings, A and B.

A shift on A consists of taking string A and moving the leftmost character to the rightmost position. For example, if A = 'abcde', then it will be 'bcdea' after one shift on A. Return True if and only if A can become B after some number of shifts on A."

My original solution is commented out:

```
var rotateString = function(A, B) {
//     if(A.length != B.length) return false;
//     if(A === B) return true;
    
//     let dynamicString = A;
//     let firstChar = '';
//     for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
//         firstChar = dynamicString[0];
//         dynamicString = dynamicString.slice(1, dynamicString.length);
//         dynamicString = dynamicString + firstChar;
//         if(dynamicString === B) {
//             return true;
//         }
//     }
//     return false
    
    if(A.length != B.length) return false;
    if(A === B) return true;
    
    let longString = B + B;
    if(longString.includes(A)) return true;
    else return false;
};
```

Let me know if my question doesn't make sense and I will clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Post the two solutions as separate, runnable, code snippets. Nobody — ! — wants to dig through “commented out” code to attempt to restore what the other behavior is.

Comment: Then, consider using a JS benchmark site, in addition to the code in the question, to quickly share — and test hypothesis about — different code snippets.

Comment: Anyway, the first approach _clearly does something else_ from “under the hood”, as it dynamically builds a new string. That’s also a very slow way to build up strings, due to the excessive copying.

Comment: tldr; The second method uses _one_ string concat, and _a different algorithm_, so using the same algorithm in the first example (with a manually written “index of / includes”) would have the same runtime bounds.

Comment: First implementation is not O(n) but O(n^2), because slice is O(n) (and string concatenation might be O(n) too, but I am not sure).

Comment: The wikipedia entry for "Big O Notation" describes it best:  "In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their run time or space requirements grow as the input size grows."  That is, Big O is not a specific measure of the performance of an algorithm, but rather, an indicator as to how it will perform relative to itself as the input size grows.  Eg, O(n^2) means that if you triple (3x) your input, that the time and/or space requirements for your algorithm will grow by ~9x.